# Combining 2 regexes, one with exact match using OR operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to combine:

```
^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\\- .]*$
```

with

```
(\W|^)first\sname(\W|$)
```

which should check for the exact phrase, first name, if that is correct. It should match either the first regex OR the second exact match. I tried this, but appears invalid:

```
^(([a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\\- .]*$)|((\W|^)first\sname(\W|$))
```

This is in javascript btw.

Comment: Maybe just [`/^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\- .]*$|(\W|^)first\sname(\W|$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/cC4hU6/1)?

Comment: stribizhev is right, the only problem with the way you combined your regexes is all those unnecessary parentheses you added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining regular expressions generally can be done simply in the following way:

Regex1 + Regex2 = (Regex1|Regex2)

```
^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\\- .]*$
    + (\W|^)first\sname(\W|$) =
(^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\\- .]*$|(\W|^)first\sname(\W|$))
```

---

Because some SO users have a hard time understand the math analogy, here's a full word explanation.

If you have a regex with content `REGEX1` and a second regex with content `REGEX2` and you want to combine them in the way that was described by OP in his question, a simple way to do this without optimization is the following.

```
(REGEX1|REGEX2)
```

Where you surround both regular expressions with parenthesis and divide the two with `|`.

Your regex would be the following:

```
(^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\\- .]*$|(\W|^)first\sname(\W|$))
```

Your first regex has an error in it, though, that makes it invalid. Try this instead.

```
(^[a-zA-Z.][a-zA-Z'\- .]*$|(\W|^)first\sname(\W|$))
```

You had `\\` in the second character class where you wanted `\`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first regex is messed up. You don't need to double escape characters. Therefore

```
\\-
```

Will match an ascii character between `\`(92) and (32). Remove one of the slashes.

[Reference](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: OP has not shown any code. What if the expression is used in the constructor notation?